# How to install hive on EMR task/slave nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, hive, emr

I got hive running on EMR master node, but I need to run hive command line on EMR task/slave node.

Anyone got idea how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Is there anything in particular that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have some shell script on slave node running hive from command line

Answer (score 3):

Hive is only traditionally run on the Master node.

Hive creates a MapReduce task that is then executed by the cluster. Hive does not actually do distributed work. It simply translates requests into jobs, submits the jobs, then handles the results.

This is different to Apache Spark, which actually has executors on slave nodes too.